# How to fix strcpy so that it detects overlapping strings

Tags: c, overlap, strcpy

In an interview, I was asked to write an implementation of [`strcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) and then fix it so that it properly handles overlapping strings. My implementation is below and it is very naive. How do I fix it so that:

1. It detects overlapping strings and
2. after detecting, how do we deal with the overlap and proceed?

---

```
char* my_strcpy(char *a, char *b) {

     if (a == NULL || b == NULL) {
         return NULL;
     }
     if (a > b) {
         //we have an overlap?
         return NULL;
     }
     char *n = a;

     while (*b != '\0') {
         *a = *b;
         a++;
         b++;
     }
     *a = '\0';
     return n;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char str1[] = "wazzupdude";
    char *after_cpy = my_strcpy(str1 + 2, str1);
    return 0;
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

So one possible implementation based on **@Secure's** answer is:

```
char* my_strcpy(char *a, char *b) {

    if (a == NULL || b == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    memmove(a, b, strlen(b) + 1);
    return a;
}
```

If we don't rely on [`memmove`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memmove), then

```
char* my_strcpy(char *a, char *b) {

    if (a == NULL || b == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    if (a == b) {
        return a;
    }

    // case1: b is placed further in the memory
    if ( a <= b && a + strlen(a) > b ) {
        char *n = a;

        while(*b != '\0') {
            *a = *b;
            a++; b++;
        }
        *a = '\0';
        return n;
    }

    // case 2: a is further in memory
    else if ( b <= a && b + strlen(b) > a ) { 
        char *src = b + strlen(b) - 1; // src points to end of b
        char *dest = a;

        while(src != b) {
            *dest = *src;
            dest--; src--;  // not sure about this..
        }
        *a = '\0';
        return a;
    }
}
```

Comment: How is `a > b` supposed to "detect an overlap"? It merely tests the two addresses.

Comment: You could do two copies: first copy to a local buffer, with no chance of overlap, then from the local buffer to the destination.

Comment: @pmg: you could, but then `my_strcpy` would have to be allowed to fail ENOMEM.

Comment: @Steve: right -- "There ain't no such thing as a free lunch"; although doing two copies is very far from a *free lunch* in the first place :-)

Comment: Regarding your edit, as an interviewer my very next question would be: Why would you not rely on memmove, and instead trade a one-liner against an unmaintainable pointer handling mess?

Comment: actually...i would first rely on memmove and if the interviewer asks for the gory details or insists i cannot use memmove i would give a detailed implementation...btw..is the implementation above correct?

Comment: Correct? I regard to portability, as said, you're invoking undefined behaviour when the two pointers are from different arrays. There's an obvious error, you're using `strlen(a)`, but that's easy to solve. `*dest = '\0';` sets the first byte of `a`, not the last byte. But most importantly, you've missed the case that the strings do *not* overlap...

Comment: @Secure: The case where they do not overlap would be implemented in the same way as case1. However,I am not able to visualize the second case(a is further in memory)..hence the coding errors.I have made some edits though but I will appreciate it if you can help me visualize case 2

Comment: I have edited my answer with a visualization of case 2.

Comment: Note: `if(a == NULL || b == NULL){ return NULL; }` is not needed if `a`, `b` point to C strings.

Comment: Shouldn't the "char *dest = a;" to the end of the equivalent destination and count down from there, if you are counting down from current position, aren't you buffer under-flowing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no portable way to detect this. You have to do pointer comparisons, and these are only defined within the same object. I.e. if the two strings do not overlap and are in fact different objects, then the pointer comparisons give you undefined behaviour.

I would let the standard library handle this, by using `memmove(a, b, strlen(b) + 1)`.

EDIT:

As Steve Jessop pointed out in the comments, there actually is a portable but *slow* way to detect overlap in this case. Compare each address within b with the first and last address of a for equality. The equality comparison with `==` is always well defined.

So you have something like this:

```
l = strlen(b);
isoverlap = 0;
for (i = 0; i <= l; i++)
{
    if ((b + i == a) || (b + i == a + l))        
    {
        isoverlap = 1;
        break;
    }
}
```

EDIT 2: Visualization of case 2

You have something like the following array and pointers:

```
S t r i n g 0 _ _ _ _ _ _ _
^       ^
|       |
b       a
```

Note that `b + strlen(b)` results in a pointer to the terminating \0. Start one behind, else you need extra handling of edge cases. It is valid to set the pointers there, you just can't dereference them.

```
src = b + strlen(b) + 1;
dst = a + strlen(b) + 1;

S t r i n g 0 _ _ _ _ _ _ _
^       ^     ^       ^  
|       |     |       |
b       a     src     dst
```

Now the copy loop which copies the \0, too.

```
while (src > b)
{
    src--; dst--;
    *dst = *src;
}
```

The first step gives this:

```
src--; dst--;

S t r i n g 0 _ _ _ _ _ _ _
^       ^   ^       ^  
|       |   |       |
b       a   src     dst

*dst = *src;

S t r i n g 0 _ _ _ 0 _ _ _
^       ^   ^       ^  
|       |   |       |
b       a   src     dst
```

And so on, until `src` ends up equal to `b`:

```
S t r i S t r i n g 0 _ _ _
^       ^              
|       |            
b       a          
src     dst
```

If you want it a bit more hackish, you could compress it further, but I don't recommend this:

```
while (src > b)
    *(--dst) = *(--src);
```

Comment: It's not true that overlap can't be detected portably. There is a shockingly inefficent way. This is for memmove, but I believe it can be adapted for strcpy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023320/how-to-implement-memmove-in-standard-c-without-an-intermediate-copy/4023563#4023563

Comment: "You have to do pointer comparisons, and these are only defined within the same object." -How do I check if the two pointers point to the same object (an array in this case)

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Correct, but in this case it can't be detected portably, because you only have two pointers, but not the array boundaries (start address and size) they're pointing into.

Comment: @user639309: It must be given as a known precondition. Else you can't check for it without invoking undefined behaviour if they're not, except when the array boundaries are known as Steve pointed out. Then you can check each possible address inside one of the arrays to be equal to the other pointer. OTOH, if you know the boundaries for *both* arrays, you can simply check them for equality. An equality check of pointers with == is always well defined, the same-object rule applies only for less than or greater than checks.

Comment: @Secure: But as you've said yourself, `strlen(b)+1` gives you that size. It only goes wrong if the caller has done something invalid first, e.g. if `a` doesn't point to a big enough buffer, but that's not our fault.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: But the string can be in the middle of a much larger array. If `a` points to a position before `b` within this array, you can't check for this.

Comment: @Secure: yes you can. My code on that `memmove` question does. If `a` is before `b`, and the regions we care about for `strcpy` overlap, then for some `l < strlen(b)+1` you hit `a + l == b`.

Comment: @Steve: Forget my last comment, I understand what you mean. You're right when checking `a` and `a + strlen(b)` for equality within `b`. This will work fine, but slow. ;)

Comment: The strings overlap if `a + strlen(a) == b + strlen(b)`.

Comment: "pointer comparisons are only defined within the same object" - so what? if string pointers do not belong to the same object, they can't overlap anyway, so the undefined behavior won't do any harm. which means, simple comparison is in fact portable!

Comment: @szulat: Comparisons of unrelated pointers do not merely yield an unspecified result.  Some compilers may infer that because the Standard imposes no requirements on what should happen if unrelated pointers are compared, the Standard thus imposes no requirements on what a program should do if given inputs that would result in such pointers being compared.  Such compilers could then further infer that if a condition could only be true when given inputs which would invoke Undefined Behavior, a compiler may assume the condition is always false.  Consequently, there is no safe Undefined Behavior.

Comment: 1)src = b + strlen(b) + 1; dst = a + strlen(b) + 1; should be src = b + strlen(b);dst = a + strlen(b) ;2)it's wrong while b>a and a+strlen(b) > b.

Comment: @CarlNorum I know it's a late comment (almost 5 years to the day!) but (as I understand it) you can't safely use `strlen(a)` because you don't know how the memory at `a` is laid out.

Comment: @TripeHound - if you’re not passing strings, it’s game over, yes. That’s not really part of the problem, though. My point was just this: if the strings overlap, they necessarily share the same null terminator. So you have to make only one comparison, not many.

Comment: @CarlNorum Technically, the _memory_ could overlap but the _strings_ don't. `a` (the destination) could be something like `abc\0def\0ghijklmnop\0` with `b` pointing at the `ghijklmnop` (you might get something like this from `strtok()`). The _strings_ at `a` (`abc`) and at `b` (`ghijklmnop`) don't overlap, but the memory that you would want `strcpy( a, b )` to copy (if this were allowed) _would_ overlap.

Comment: @Carl Not necessarily... what led me here was a recent compile under gcc (of some very old code) producing the "wrong" result for a "shift-left" copy. (Technically, the result can't be "wrong", because as we were [mis]using `strcpy`, the result is undefined, but wrong in the sense of "not what we expected and happened to work for years").

Answer (score 4):

You could probably use memmove() if you expect the strings to be overlapping.

```
char* my_strcpy(char *a, char *b)
{
    memmove(a, b, strlen(b) + 1);
    return a;
}
```

Comment: That's taking into account that one char == one byte. I'd change strlen(b) + 1 by ( strlen(b) + 1 ) * sizeof( char )

Comment: sizeof(char) is always exactly one byte.

Comment: Yep, but memmove expects bytes, not chars, even if they incidentally have the same size. Anyway, I just said "I would".

Comment: @Baltasarq  "memmove expects bytes, not chars" is misleading.  `memmove()` expects a size in characters and in C, "bytes" and character have the same size.  "The memmove function copies n characters from the object pointed to by s2 into the object pointed to by s1. C11 "7.24.2.2"

Answer (score 4):

Note: Here, `b` is the address of the source string and `a` is the address of the destination.

With `a > b` you wouldn't necessarily have an overlap. If

```
(a <= b && a+strlen(a) >= b) || (b <= a && b+strlen(b) >= a)
```

then you have an overlap.

However, besides detecting overlap for the sake of interview, `a > b` should do fine for `strcpy`. The idea is this:

If `b` is placed further in the memory (`b > a`), then you can normally copy `b` into `a`. Parts of `b` will be overwritten, but you are already past that part.

If `a` is placed further in the memory (`a > b`), it means that **possibly** by writing on the first location of `a`, you have already overwritten a location in `b` with a higher index. In such a case, you should copy in the opposite direction. So instead of copy from index `0` to `strlen(b)-1`, you should copy from `strlen(b)-1` to `0`.

If you are confused how that helps, draw two overlapping arrays on paper and try to copy once from the beginning of the array and once from the end. Try this with the overlapping arrays both in cases `a > b` and `a < b`.

Note, if `a == b`, you don't need to actually copy anything and you can just return.

Edit: I am not sure, but reading the other solutions, it seems like this answer may not be completely portable. Beware of that.

Comment: if `a==b`, you could even just return :-) `strcpy` takes pointers-to-non-volatile, so there's no requirement to actually touch the memory. That said, it's not worth adding code to optimize that absurd case.

Comment: @chux, did you take the terminating NUL into account?

Answer (score 3):

```
if a > b; then
    copy a from the beginning
else if a < b; then
    copy a from the ending
else // a == b
    do nothing
```

You can refer to an [implementation](http://www.student.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~cs350/common/os161-src-html/memmove_8c-source.html) of `memmove`, it's quite like what I said.

Comment: `a > b` risks UB when `a` and `b` are in different objects - so not a portable solution.

Answer (score 2):

Even without using relational pointer comparisons, `memmove`, or equivalent, it is possible to code a version of `strcpy` which will be performed as an `strlen` and `memcpy` in the non-overlapping case, and as a top-down copy in the overlapping case.  The key is to exploit the fact that if the first byte of the destination is read and then replaced with zero, calling `strlen` on the source and adding to the source pointer the value that was returned will yield a legitimate pointer which will equal the start of the destination in the "troublesome overlap" case.  If the source and destination are different objects, the "source plus strlen" pointer may be safely computed and observed to be unequal to the destination.

In the event that adding the string length to the source pointer yields the destination pointer, replacing the zero byte with the earlier-read value and calling strlen on the destination will allow code to determine the ending address of the source and destination strings.  Further, the length of the source string will indicate the distance between the pointers.  If this value is large (probably greater than 16 or so), code may efficiently subdivide the "move" operation into a top-down sequence of memcpy operations.  Otherwise the string may be copied with a top-down loop of single-byte copy operations, or with a sequence of "memcpy to source to buffer"/"memcpy buffer to destination" operations [if the per-byte cost of a large memcpy is less than half that of an individual-character-copy loop, using a ~256-byte buffer may be a useful optimization].

Comment: "first byte of the destination is read and then replaced with zero," --> Interesting.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (a>= b && a <= b+strlen(b))) || (b+strlen(b) >= a && b+strlen(b) <= a + strlen(b))
```

(*) you should cache strlen(b) to improve performance

**What it does:**

checks if the `a+len` [address of a + extra len bytes] is inside the string, or `a` [address of a] is inside the string, these are the only possibilities for a string overlapping.

Comment: `a>= b` risks UB when `a` and `b` are in different objects - so not a portable solution.

Answer (score 1):

I was asked this in a recent interview. We don't have to 'detect' overlap. We can write `strcpy` in such a way that overlapping addresses are taken care of. The key is to copy from the end of source string instead of from the start.

Here is a quick code.

```
void str_copy(const char *src, char *dst) 
{
    /* error checks */

    int i = strlen(a); /* may have to account for null character */

    while(i >= 0) 
    {
        dst[i] = src[i];  
        i--; 
    }
}
```

EDIT: This only works when a < b. For a > b, copy from the start.

Comment: The problem persists in case of overlapping strings. Like `memcpy`, you should copy from beginning or the end, based on if the destination to copy has lower or higher address than the source respectively.

Comment: 1) Code does not compile.  2) Suggest re-working answer/code to use `src dest` throughout rather than `a b`.  3) `strlen()` returns type `size_t`, but then `size_t i` causes trouble with `while(i>=0)` test which is always true.

Answer (score 1):

If these two strings overlap, then, while copying you'll run over the original `a` or `b` pointers.

Assuming that strcpy( a, b ) roughly means a <- b, i.e., the first parameter is the destination of the copy, then you only check whether the copy pointer reaches `b`'s position.

You only need to save the `b` original position, and while copying, check you haven't reached it. Also, don't write the trailing zero if you have reached that position.

```
 char* my_strcpy(char *a, const char *b)
 {

    if ( a == NULL
      || b == NULL )
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    char *n = a;
    const char * oldB = b;

    while( *b != '\0'
       &&  a != oldB )
    {
        *a = *b;
        a++;
        b++;
    }

    if ( a != oldB ) {
        *a = '\0';
    }

    return n;
 }
```

This algorithm just stops copying. Maybe you want to do something else, such as marking the error condition, or add an end-of-the string mark to the previous position (though failing silently (as the algorithm does at the moment) isn't the best option).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This SO entry is already older, but I am currently working on a old piece of code that copies overlapping strings with `strcpy()`. Characters were missing in the log output. I decided to use the following compact solution, which copies `char` by `char`.

```
static char *overlapped_strcpy(char *dest, const char *src)
{
  char *dst = dest;

  if (dest == NULL || src == NULL || dest == src)
    return dest;

  do {
    *dst++ = *src;
  } while (*src++);

  return dest;
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

As @Gerhardh pointed out, the code above only works if `dest <= src` (I just had to solve this case). For the case `dest > src` it is more complicated. However, copying from behind, as other answers have already mentioned, leads to success. For example:

```
if (dest <= src) {
  /* do the above */
} else {
  int i = (int)strlen(src);
  while (i >= 0) {
    dst[i] = src[i];
    i--;
  }
}
```

Comment: How does this address the overlapping part? Let's assume `strlen(src) == 20` and `dest=src+5`

Comment: @Gerhardh I only had to solve `strcpy(posPtr, posPtr+2);`. The opposite case would be a mess.

Comment: Detecting and handling the mess would be the whole point of such a function. ;)

Comment: `dest <= src` risks UB when `dest` and `src` are in different objects - so not a portable solution.