# Copying a substring to the start of the string in C

Tags: c, string, memory, strcpy

I am trying to remove the whitespace at the start of a string, I have the index of the first non whitespace character, so I tried to do this:

```
int firstNonWhitespace = ...;
char *line = ...;
char *realStart = line + firstNonWhiteSpace;
strcpy(line, realStart);
```

but got Abort Trap 6 when at runtime.

However it works if I copy the realStart string to a temporary string, and then copy the temporary string to line:

```
int firstNonWhitespace = ...;
char *line = ...;
char *realStart = line + firstNonWhiteSpace;
char *tstring = malloc(strlen(realStart) + 1);
strcpy(tstring, realStart);
strncpy(line, tstring, strlen(line));
free(tstring);
```

Comment: For all practical purposes, can't you just use the realStart to refer to the string from there onwards?

Comment: ["If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined."](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strcpy.html).

Comment: Please spell out "char *line = ...;" What did you replace with ...?

Comment: `strcpy` doesn't like overlapping strings. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427596/how-to-fix-strcpy-so-that-it-detects-overlapping-strings for several alternatives.

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems with your code.

1. The source and destination in the call to `strcpy()` do overlap, which results in Undefined Behaviour.
2. It might well be the case that `realStart` points to some non-writeable area of memory.

Answer (score 1):

The faster way is

```
line += firstNonWhiteSpace;
```

but that might have consequences for your memory management, in case that part of memory was dynamically allocated. Only do this if you know what you are doing.

Comment: But that will not affect the string after the function returns. And the function is not passed a pointer to a string

Comment: What function? I have no crystal ball, only those few lines you posted and they say not much about your environment.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
    char a[] = "        hey";
    int i = 0;
    char *p = a;
    while(a[i++] == ' ');

    strcpy(p, p + i - 1);
    printf("%s\n", a);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is likely that you are not allowed to modify string literals, i. e. the code

```
int main() {
    int firstNonWhitespace = 3;
    char *line = "   foo";
    char *realStart = line + firstNonWhiteSpace;
    strcpy(line, realStart);
}
```

may or may not work depending on whether your platform protects against modifying the string literal `"   foo"`. Copying the string first is required by the language standard.

Also, since `strcpy()` is not guaranteed to work correctly on overlapping strings (you might get lucky, though), use `memmove()` to do the moving.