# Why is Linux memmove() implemented the way it is?

Tags: c, implementation, memmove

From the Linux manpage for [memmove(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memmove)

> The memmove() function copies n bytes from memory area src to memory area dest.
>   The memory areas may overlap: copying takes place as though the bytes in src are
>   first copied into a temporary array that does not overlap src or dest, and the
>   bytes are then copied from the temporary array to dest.

Instead of allocating a temporary array and copy the values twice we could just do the following:

```
void *my_memmove(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n) {
  signed char operation;
  size_t end;
  size_t current;

  if(dest != src) {
    if(dest < src) {
      operation = 1;
      current = 0;
      end = n;
    } else {
      operation = -1;
      current = n - 1;
      end = -1;
    }

    for( ; current != end; current += operation) {
      *(((unsigned char*)dest) + current) = *(((unsigned char*)src) + current);
    }
  }
  return dest;
}
```

In this implementation we simply take care of the position where we begin to copy.

Is there a drawback in my implementation?

*Note: I won't actually use my implementation. I'm just curious.*

Comment: `dest < src` is undefined behavior when `dest` and `src` point to different blocks. Function `memmove()` is specified to work when `dest` and `src` point to the same block, but it is not specified that it has to be called with pointers to the same block. See the related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023320/how-to-implement-memmove-in-standard-c-without-an-intermediate-copy

Comment: I think you missed "as though" in manpage. It does not actually work that way.

Comment: You can compare your implementation with [FreeBSD's `bcopy`](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/string/bcopy.c?v=FREEBSD-LIBC), the underlying code for their memmove(). It also supports copying backwards, without a temporary buffer.

Comment: Your implementation is actually incorrect/invalid. In the expression `current += operation`, operation is converted to `size_t` and thus becomes `SIZE_MAX`, not -1.

Comment: @R.. Why does this matter? `current + (size_t)-1` still computes `current - 1`.

Comment: Indeed, you're right. I was thinking the `(size_t)-1` was being added directly to a pointer, but it's not; it's modifying `current` in a well-defined way.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can look at some source code for memmove [here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/BerkeleyDB/BerkeleyDB-6/db/clib/memmove.c), [here](https://www.student.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~cs350/common/os161-src-html/doxygen/html/memmove_8c_source.html), [here](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=string/memmove.c;h=bf7dcc162770503ed62a262f627bfa526fc5a0d7;hb=HEAD), and [here](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/x86_64/memmove.S;h=9e693f2a9806fa8f6ce7e26f37b1808e952396d3;hb=HEAD).

What you'll notice is that they don't *actually* make a temporary array.  The man pages are written to help you understand what it is doing *logically*, not *actually*.  Hence, they say "as though".

What memmove() actually does is copy the bytes from `src` to `dest`, and it copies forward if `dest < src` (which is essentially the same thing as memcpy), and backwards otherwise.

The difference between `memcpy` and `memmove` is that `memcpy` blindly copies forward - which is why `dest` and `src` should not overlap.  But `memmove` takes the precaution of ensuring the overlap will not screw up the end result.

Comment: Excellent points. The C source to Linux memmove is [here](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=string/memmove.c;h=bf7dcc162770503ed62a262f627bfa526fc5a0d7;hb=HEAD), but it's largely irrelevant because the actual `memmove` is implemented [in hand-optimized assembly](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/x86_64/memcpy.S;h=9e693f2a9806fa8f6ce7e26f37b1808e952396d3;hb=HEAD), which definietely doesn't copy to a temp array. As a curiosity, it is defined exactly the same as `memcpy`, because on its target architecture there is no penalty from doing it that way.