# Does memmove use dynamic memory for its temporary array

Tags: c, memory

According to [C11 N1570 standard draft](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

7.24.2.2 "The `memmove` function":

> The `memmove` function copies `n` characters from the object pointed to by `s2` into the object pointed to by `s1`. **Copying takes place as if the `n` characters from the object pointed to by `s2` are first copied into a temporary array of `n` characters** that does not overlap the objects pointed to by `s1` and `s2`, and then the `n` characters from the temporary array are copied into the object pointed to by `s1`

So if I choose to move a buffer of size 32K using (file_size = 32K)

```
memmove(io_Buffer, io_Buffer+17, file_size);
```

won't the temp buffer be of size 32K?

**Question**

Can the program allocate dynamic memory on its own? Does it allocate and free the memory in that one line?

Comment: Try [`ltrace`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/462710/32558), read glibc source, read GCC source, step debug the assembly, and pray that it does not go too deep :-)

Comment: @CiroSantilli新疆改造中心六四事件法轮功 This was for an embedded application (and.. that's why I was too concerned about the memory), but will try out `ltrace` for sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you missed the "as if" in that sentence. That means the effects will be the same as if it did that, not that it will actually do that. I've never seen an implementation of `memmove` that actually uses a temporary array.

Comment: Thank you. Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13339582/why-is-linux-memmove-implemented-the-way-it-is) other question which points to a few implementations. Also, cheers on Ripple!

Answer (score 1):

The `memmove` is not a single implementation in modern compilers; it is considered an intrinsic instead. It is easiest to show with an example how the *"as if"* works:

```
#include <string.h>

void test_memmove(void * restrict dst, const void * restrict src, size_t n) {
    memmove(dst, src, n);
}
```

the `restrict` in parameters tell that the memory accessed through the pointers do not overlap. So GCC [knows to compile this to](https://godbolt.org/z/qzfX67)

```
test_memmove:
        jmp     memcpy
```

Because the compiler was able to take the `restrict` into account and "prove" that the memory areas pointed to by these 2 do not overlap, the call to `memmove` was immediately changed to a (tail) call to `memcpy`!