# Using comparison operators with pointers to check if it is within an address range?

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers, memory-management

I'm implementing a function that deallocates a memory location that has been supplied to it, via a call to `deallocate_cache(void *ptr)`.

My memory constructs for the task at hand are the following:

```
 22 typedef struct slab {
 23         void *addr;
 24         int bm[((SLAB_SIZE/8)/(8*sizeof(int)))+1]; // bitmap
 25         struct slab *next;
 26 } slab;

 39 typedef struct {
 40         int alloc_unit;
 41         slab S;
 42 } cache;

 45 typedef struct { // structure for the entire memory
 46         cache C[9];
 47         region *R;
 48 } memory;
```

Hence, I have a `memory M`, which contains caches `c[0]`, `c[1]`, ..., `c[8]`, which in turn contain `slabs`. When one `slab` fills up through allocation, I allocate another one as a linked list element through the `slab *next` field.

For my `deallocate_cache(void *ptr)` to work correctly, I must first find out whether `ptr` is even in the range of the caches, and if so in which one it is. This is what I have so far:

```
 1.    // Check if ptr is in the range of (slab_addr, slab_size) for each slab in each cache
 2. int ci = 0, counter, coefficient, done, freeable;
 3. slab *look_ahead;
 4. for(; ci < 9; ci++){
 5.         void *max_addr = &M.C[ci].S + SLAB_SIZE; // The upper bound of the address range of the first slab
 6.         counter = 1;
 7.         look_ahead = &M.C[ci].S;
 8.         while(look_ahead->next != NULL){
 9.             if( ptr > look_ahead->addr && ptr > max_addr){ // Check ptr is greater than S.addr. If yes, it's a good bet it's in this cache.
10.                 look_ahead = look_ahead->next;
11.                 max_addr += SLAB_SIZE; // Now the upper bound of the address range of the following slab
12.                 counter++; // slab counter, 1-based counting
13.             }
14.             else {
15.                     done = 1;
16.                     break;
17.             }
18.         }
19.         if(done == 1) break;
20.
21. }
```

Unfortunately, and rather obviously, this does not work as intended. Is there any way I could use pointers like this to compare addresses, or check if the pointer is in a given address range? Or will I have to simply compare every single address in the maximum range I know I have allocated to? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I don't get something. If you slab is a linked list, why do you need 9 differente cache ? Are you trying to minimize the number of element in each slab ? If so why 9 cache ?
I don't expect "max_addr += SLAB_SIZE" to work properly. A linked list doesn't have to be continue in memory (that's why you give it a pointer). Following what you do, you probably wanted to do: "max_addr = look_ahead->next + SLAB_SIZE".
This still seems odd to me, but at least it's following what you did previously

Comment: My apologies, perhaps I could have been clearer. The caches serve for different sized `slabs`: c[0] holds only slabs which contain 8-byte allocations (up to 8192 per `slab`, 8192 being equal to `SLAB_SIZE / M.C[0].alloc_unit`), c[1] holds slabs containing 16-byte allocations, and so on.  I'll look into your suggestion, thank you.

Comment: Somewhat related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023320/how-to-implement-memmove-in-standard-c-without-an-intermediate-copy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you cannot add anything to or subtract anything from a pointer to `void`.

Pointer arithmetic is defined only for pointers that point to things of known sizes. `void`, unlike `char` or `int` or `char*` or `struct slab`, does not have a known size. And that's because adding to or subtracting from a pointer advances the address in the pointer by a multiple of the size of what the pointer points to.

So, if you have `char* p;` then `p = p + 1;` adds `sizeof(char)` (which is 1) to the address in the pointer, but if you have `long* p;` then `p = p + 1;` adds `sizeof(long)` (which typically is 2, 4 or 8) to the address in the pointer.

However odd, the same limitation applies to comparing pointers with `>`, `<`, `>=`, `<=`. The compared pointers must point to the same type, which can't be `void`.

I think you need to use pointers to `char` instead of pointers to `void` or cast the latter to the former in order to do pointer arithmetic.

Another important thing to note is that legally you can't compare pointers with `>`, `<`, `>=`, `<=` if these pointers do not point into the same array or into the same object (which can be aggregate like a structure). The C standard states that this amounts to undefined behavior.

So, if you allocate two objects separately (as declarations of separate objects or as separate calls to `malloc()` or similar), then you can't legally compare pointers to these two objects with `>`, `<`, `>=`, `<=`.

`==` and `!=` can be done, however.

One common workaround for this comparison limitation is to cast pointers to `uintptr_t`, an unsigned integer type that is guaranteed to be able to hold a pointer, and perform regular arithmetic operations on this integer type and then, if needed, convert (cast) it back to a pointer type.

This, of course, will only work if your compiler defines pointer to integer and integer to pointer conversions meaningfully and guarantees that the integer values obtained from converting pointers to them are memory address.

Use this info to correct your code.

Comment: My apologies for the late acceptance, but thank you very much for your informative answer! I ended up casting to char to fix the issue.