# memmove implementation

Tags: c, memmove

In reference to the thread: [memmove implementation in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572309/memmove-implementation-in-c), I did not understand why would there be a memory overlap for 2 different variables? i.e. is this a normal scenario that the compiler allocates same 'common space' to 2 different variables and why is this policy used by compilers in such cases?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nothing to do with the compiler.  Consider the following:

```
int x[100];

memmove(&x[1], &x[0], 99*sizeof(int));
```

Answer (score 6):

It's not really about the compiler creating variables that overlap. It's simply that the specification of `memmove` says it has to work, even if the source and destination overlap. If there's no chance of the two overlapping, you usually want to use `memcpy`, which will usually be faster, but gives undefined behavior if they do overlap.